# Large number of null variables with the total size exceeding the memory in C

Tags: c++, c

I have a very basic question related to NULL variables in C. Consider a hypothetical 64-bit system with very limited memory say 4KB and with a large number of integer pointers all set to NULL, such that the total size exceeds the available memory. Will such a program compile and execute?
Assume that the program doesn't have to do anything meaningful, just do declarations to a bunch of null integer pointers(of the sort int *x = NULL) and terminate.

Comment: Even the 8086 had at most 1 MiB of memory. ^^

Comment: Are the null pointers in global or local scope?

Comment: Are you allowing optimizations?

Comment: The compiler and linker do not know or care whether there is enough memory to execute the program. But if you have a 64-bit system with only 4KB memory available, throw it into the sea.

Comment: 'hypothetical 64-bit system with very limited memory say 4KB'... next.

Comment: @MartinJames , Ok, that was a poor choice of words. I wanted to emphasize the "relatively small memory" part and not 4KB. I had expected you to understand that but I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @cad No optimizations. But I got my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you did this:

```
 int *x = NULL;
```

memory is still allocated for storing the pointer `x` (despite there being NULL on the right hand side). Memory in such case, if x is automatic variable was allocated on the stack.
If you had used `malloc` on the right hand side you would additionally have claimed memory from the heap.

Now if you create many such pointers which will exceed available stack memory you will get stack overflow on run time - but if you don't use these pointers they might as well get optimized away.

Comment: They are only allocated on the stack if they are local variables.  Global variables will be allocated differently.

Comment: @EricJ.:Ok, I addressed local variables, I can't cover all cases:)

Comment: Hmmm well there are only three total cases... (stack, global and heap)

Comment: @EricJ. Please use the appropriate term: a variable with *function scope* is a variable declared inside a function, an *automatic*  variable is one stored on the stack. The term “local variable” is ambiguous and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Eric J. There are certainly many architectures where C is used that has many more (or less) locations for memory than 3. FWIW, "heap" and "stack" are not even in the C spec.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Thanks for the clarification.  It's been 20 years since I wrote much C, going from rusty memory.

Comment: @chux: I know that the implementation of storage isn't in the spec, though I have not worked with an architecture that didn't implement automatic variables on the stack, global variables in a data segment or similar and dynamic memory in a (or several) heap-like structure.  There's registers as a compiler optimization for some storage.  I'll take your word for it that some real architectures follow different storage allocation strategies.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare but don't use a variable which has no side effects the compiler will optimize it out of existence. So no, this is not a way to go out of memory.

If you don't have optimizations turned on, you could create enough variables on the stack to cause a stack overflow. You could also just create a really big array on the stack.

That said, it's quite easy to run out of memory, and you don't need to do it with copious quantities of `int` pointers. No matter how you manage to run out of memory, it won't stop you from compiling the program successfully.

Comment: `the compiler will optimize it out of existence` Probably for any real, modern C compiler but that behavior is not guaranteed by the C spec.  The question is pretty theoretical, so the answer should not assume a real-world implementation.

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, there is no guarantee of this behavior. But I'm leaving the answer alone. No reason to overly-pedanticize an answer to this sort of question.

Comment: Up to you.  When the question states something like `Consider a hypothetical 64-bit system with very limited memory say 4KB` I tend to be more pedantic because I'm probably not dealing with a real system, but rather with a question that is trying to tease out edge cases or is attempting to understand the limits of a system.